# How to spoof javascript window.name property in chrome based browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, javascript

I was trying everything to alter the tab name property but it doesnt seem to be working with browsers using chrome API. As far as firefox is concerned, there are no problems whatsoever with anonymization, most if not all modding could be done thru config section, additionally there exist tons of plugins doing all the magic. But it appears to not be that straightforward with chromium. I want a uniform solution for both chromium and firefox, preferably tampermonkey script.

I wrote this code

```
@ //include http:/*/
@ //https://*/*
@ //run-at document-start
var old = window.name;
window.name = "";
```

but it doesnt work. [This site](http://ip-check.info) is still able to report that the tab name is not obfuscated. What am I doing wrong?